# Html5 page structure issue

Tags: css, html

I have creating one web page using html5

Here is my code:

```
<header>
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  <hr class="hr-style">
  <h1>The Articles</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section>
  <article class="article">
    <img src="img/articles.png" alt="articles" />
  </article>
  <aside class="aside">
    <img src="img/agencies.png" alt="agencies" />
  </aside>
</section>

<footer>
</footer>
```

This is my JSfiddle i tried: please see this what i tried,

http://jsfiddle.net/3jet0dfu/

I need like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm new to HTML5, i need to know how to align the page using html5 tag.

Comment: **Align it how?** It's not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Read a little bit more about HTML5 please. As always, you need to use CSS to style your page, even with HTML5 semantic tags.

Comment: HTML5 isn't a tag, for starters.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3jet0dfu/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D: I tried possible html5 tags and css styles. after it shows like as my jsfiddle link. There is some mistakes contained, how to align by using css styles?

Comment: @888, If u kno html and  css there is not a big deal to learn html5.. Just write every tag <header> , <section> for css. and pls if you can just note how arrange your website what you have given is not clear and people will downgrade u !!

Comment: @Donal: Thanks for your response, in header the logo image is top of the header, i need like this http://s27.postimg.org/5n9gm4g0z/article_page4.jpg

Comment: Just move it under <hr class="hr-style" />. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/3jet0dfu/3/

Comment: @Donal: but i need to show <hr />.

Comment: Just add a style - http://jsfiddle.net/3jet0dfu/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3jet0dfu/5/ - changed the colour on the hr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you need to contain your content with a width.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/jeveqa/1/edit)

In this example I am giving the body a width the same as your logo image (939px). `margin: 0 auto;` will center the page. Your question is too broad to give you an exact solution.

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    width: 939px;
}
```

It would be better to replace the `<hr>` with a border. For example:

```
<img src="" alt="" id="logo">
```

```
#logo {
    border-bottom: solid 2px #CCC;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

I have also done a crude CSS reset to remove the default margins; they can then be easily controlled by adding them back to each element. You can also use a [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com) or [CSS Normalise](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) (do some research on the ideal solution for you)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

`box-sizing: border-box` is also brilliant if you want to use percentages.

[Here is an excellent run-down on box-sizing.](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This simple change gives you most of your desired layout. Now you need to change the width and add margins / padding as needed.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: :In footer the background image not display properly.

Comment: Does adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#footer` help?

Comment: your answer different from what i need.. can you help me?

Comment: @888 - What do you need?

Comment: I need like posted example,,, In footer need to apply background image .